# Issue in Wireless network

Tags: networking, wifi

I am facing weird issue in Wireless network, explained in details below:

I am using Motomesh Duo 4300 radios Total 7 no. of AP in the field 
Outdoor network Area around 3*3Km 
1 no.of IAP(connected to wired network) and 6 no. of MWR (in the filed)
Around 50 no. of clients' 
Network uses only for plain data(no voice and picture)

Issues: 1) When I ping to Intelligent Access Point (IAP) from server it is very good, like 1ms to 3ms but when I ping to other Access Points(MWR) it is very very bad ping quality and huge no. of request time out(rto)/destination host unreachable errors

2) Suddenly all Access Points(MWR) stops communication to IAP means there is no communication between IAP to MWR but at same time IAP can communicate to Clients in this particular area

3) All Access Points are communicating to each other(IAP and MWR) but there is no communication between Access Points to Clients, it is just like network hang

Kindly share anyone faced this type of issue in his /her experience.

Please suggest me, how can I get out of this.

Thanks in advance, 
Manish